# Problems installing Android Studio

Tags: linux, android-studio, google-chrome

I am unable to install Android studio. I get the following error message

Error installing Linux application

An error occured while installing your linux application

Error while installing package: cannot copy extracted data for './opt/android-studio/plugins/android/lib/android.jar' to '/opt/android-studio/plugins/android/lib/android.jar.dpkg-new'

I am running Google chrome OS Version 113.0.5672.134 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Can anyone help please?

I have searched google, android help pages and this site and have found no answers.